# how to differentiate $y(x) =exp(ax)$ twice

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm quite confused with this differentiation:

Suppose $x$ is a $m \times 1$ column vector, $a$ is a $1 \times m$ vector, I want to differentiate $\exp(ax)$ a few times. 
I think the first derivative is: 
$$
y' = a*\exp(ax)
$$

What about the second derivative? Is it $y''= a a^T\exp(ax) $? Or something else? And why?

Comment: If $a$ is a $1\times m$ vector, would'nt it be $a^Ta\exp(ax)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
{\partial^2y\over\partial x_i\partial x_j}=a_ia_j*\exp(ax).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're in doubt about taking derivatives using vectors, just remember that everything must be conformable at every step for your definitions to make sense. If I were to walk through this problem, I'd first convert every vector to a column vector to keep everything straight. That is, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{mx1}$ and $a:= a^T \in \mathbb{R}^{mx1}$.

Then we would have your function in terms of the new variable $a$:

$$y(x) = \exp{(a^T x)} = 1\times 1$$

$$\implies \cfrac{d y(x)}{dx} = \exp{(a^T x)} a = m\times 1 $$

Taking another derivative wrt $x$ yields

$$\cfrac{d^2 y(x)}{dx^2} = \exp{(a^T x)} a a^T = m\times m$$

Replacing $a$ with $a^T$ in every step would undo my initial changes to your $a$ variable.